RAM compatibility issues
I have an ASUS M2N68-AM SE2 motherboard, I want DDR2 RAM so I bought a Simmtronics 2GB DDR2 800 MHz RAM, after I plug it into my motherboard it doesn't turn on with my old RAM,
but if I plug only the new RAM it was showing "Boot Block Compatible Version Ver.026, Bad BIOS checksum. Starting BIOS Recovery..." But when I unplug the new RAM and put in the old RAM it turns on normally.

Did the RAM fault or did I buy the wrong RAM, how to buy a working RAM for my motherboard?
Two years before I bought the "Mente DDR2 800 Mhz" RAM and "Lapcare Ram 2GB DDR2 800 RAM" It also same issue it didn't turn on but also didn't show anything like "Boot block..."
I was so confused with this
In this image
Dynet 667 MHz and KingMax 800Mhz were working previously now died,
newly bought Mente 800Mhz, New Simmtronis 800Mhz, Lapcare 800Mhz doesn't work

Currently, the working ram is,


You can find the qualified vendors list (QVL) for RAM for that motherboard in the support on the Asus website.

Yeah, I've seen it, but the RAM that was not on that list is also working, and the RAM on the list is not available in India to buy.

"Did the RAM fault" - I thought you said, when you installed the original memory, everything worked? Your original memory was 667 Mhz  and you purchased 1066 Mhz memory. You did indeed purchase the wrong memory.

When I install original ram it was working, the non working ram was 800 Mhz I don't have 1066 Mhz ram, but Kingmax brand also 800Mhz it's worked before, it's not working now because of rust

I looked up the part number at least one of those modules in your screenshot is the higher frequency

No all are 800Mhz and 667Mhz

Hi, How can you say that was a higher frequency, can you explain to me,

I'd just like to add that if you try using two sticks of RAM that are not identical at the same time, you're much more likely to have issues. Other than that, I think the best answer anyone here can give is to point you to the QVL file that @Andrew Morton linked. Are you sure none of the brands on that list are available in India? There's quite a few on there.

The website Memory Stock mentions the two RAM sticks that worked for you before:

DDR2 PC2-5300 667MHz and
PC2-6400 800MHz Non-ECC DIMM

As I see to your first question the DDR2 800Mhz is too much for the board to handle you need a DDR PC2-5300 version with 667MHz. Both the ram options mentioned above seem to be buyable on Amazon in India from what I can see i.e.:

https://www.amazon.in/s?k=DDR2+PC2-5300+667MHz&crid=ZLR50ZP0AW8R&sprefix=ddr2+pc2-5300+667mhz%2Caps%2C119&ref=nb_sb_noss
https://www.amazon.in/s?k=PC2-6400+800MHz+Non-ECC+DIMM&crid=2KMCJDVX4PXJW&sprefix=pc2-6400+800mhz+non-ecc+dimm+%2Caps%2C249&ref=nb_sb_noss

Be careful here with mixing RAM, you should use two sticks of RAM that are identical to minimize issues.
However from what I can tell from reading the BIOS boot up this is not a RAM issue. Your issue is that the BIOS itself seems to be corrupted and requires recovery. You need to prepare a Recovery USB device or enter the CD that you got when you bought the motherboard. See instructions for this here.
I hope this puts you on the correct path. After you are able to boot up, I would try any of the RAM sticks that worked before that fit the MHz requirement as I mentioned above, and if you are trying two sticks, always try two of the same type!

Hi, thanks for your reply, I bought EVM DDR2 667mhz RAM it's working fine with old one. For 800Mhz some brands are working some are not i don't know why, For BIOS error issue, i tried recovery it's still not working, but this issue not occurred in 667Mhz RAM

My confusion is KingMax 800Mhz(Not listed in the QVL list) is working, but Mente 800Mhz, New Simmtronis 800Mhz, Lapcare 800Mhz is not working, showing BIOS error i don't find any difference in those,

Hi! Yeah I understand but yet again I think this BIOS issue was either caused by you wrongly inserting a RAM stick with too high of Mhz value which damaged something on the motherboard or the BIOS (hepefully) simply got corrupted because of some other issue which you simply have to restore. When you say you tried recovery, did you try it with the disk that you got with the motherboard or USB, the issue could also be with the usb being prepared in a wrong way. Anyhow you should post a new question for this with more information i.e. error messages after running recovery etc.

Hi, The ram stick was inserted properly, the ram stick was not too high it's 800Mhz and was supported by the motherboard, I am done with the recovery with USB properly as mentioned on the motherboard support page, and if I did it wrong how does the pc turning on after with the EVM DDR2 667mhz and KingMax 800Mhz RAM?
The PC gives that error with this ram only Mente 800Mhz, New Simmtronis 800Mhz, Lapcare 800Mhz.
I want the difference with EVM DDR2 667mhz, KingMax 800Mhz working ram and Mente 800Mhz, New Simmtronis 800Mhz, Lapcare 800Mhz not working ram
